# How to make `man` work for shell builtin commands and keywords?

Tags: command-line, manpage

I use the `man` command all the time when I want to get information about a specific command. But this doesn't help me too much when that specific command is a shell builtin. For example:

```
man cd
```

returns:

```
No manual entry for cd
```

My question is: it is possible to make `man` also work for all shell builtin commands (like `cd`, `alias`, `history`, etc.),  and keywords (like `if`, `while`, `[[`, `{`, etc.)?

Comment: And how come `echo` is a builtin command but has a man page?

Comment: @AvatarParto `echo` is also a system command (executable) located in `/bin`. You  can check this using `type -a echo`. The same thing happens with `time` and maybe others.

Comment: Did you explore `info bash` yet?

Comment: You can always [write your own](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs701/Handouts/man_pages.html) man pages.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `help` command when is used with `-m` option can display information about builtin commands in pseudo-manpage format. For example:

```
help -m cd | less
```

will display information about `cd` command in a format almost exactly like in a manual page.

Starting from this command you can wrap `man` command in one function in your `.bashrc` file as follow:

```bsh
man () {
    case "$(type -t -- "$1")" in
    builtin|keyword)
        help -m "$1" | sensible-pager
        ;;
    *)
        command man "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

After this `man` will work also for all shell builtin commands and keywords. For example:

```
man :
```

will display:

```
NAME
    : - Null command.

SYNOPSIS
    :

DESCRIPTION
    Null command.

    No effect; the command does nothing.

    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.

SEE ALSO
    bash(1)

IMPLEMENTATION
    GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: Very clever approach! +1

Comment: If there are executables masked by builtins, you can specify the section. `man time` vs. `man 1 time`

Comment: ...note although that if you are a `zsh` user your are not so lucky: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/1242108 (no man pages installed)

Comment: `info`, `help -m`, why can't we just have good man pages these days? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: +1 ... nice ! The behavior of yr function resembles somewhat what occurs through function overloading in C/C++... Only curiously `man type` does not produce a description of options "-a" or "-t" in Ubuntu 14.04.4.... and yet, they're there !

Comment: If you have a function shadowing a builtin (i.e. `cd() { __zsh_like_cd cd "$@" }`) then `type -t cd` will not work (it thinks `cd` is a function and tries to do `man cd`).  You can use the `-f` flag to "_suppress shell function lookup_": `type -ft -- "$1"`.

Comment: Why use `sensible-pager` and not `pager` (which can be configured using `sudo update-alternatives --config pager`)? How can the former be configured?

Answer (score 30):

```
man bash-builtins
```

This contains help snippets for the builtin commands, albeit in a slightly more condensed format than the `help` equivalent.

Comment: Good to know! It's from section 7 of the manual. I didn't heard about this manual page until now. +1, but I can't accept this answer because it's not exactly what I asked.

Comment: On macOS High Sierra that command is simply "man builtins"

Answer (score 13):

You can install manual pages about using a [POSIX system for development](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/manpages-posix-dev) as,

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
```

It will provide man pages for shell builtins.

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Now try,

```
$ man cd
CD(P)                      POSIX Programmer's Manual                      CD(P)

NAME
   cd - change the working directory

SYNOPSIS
   cd [-L | -P] [directory]


...
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to came with this answer. But the problem is that this will only work for some builtins - [those specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01).

Comment: Bash does not strictly adhere to POSIX unless run in POSIX mode, so these man pages may not be comprehensive, and may be wrong in some circumstances, especially when describing the behaviour of certain features.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu yes you are absolutely correct, it will work for some builtins.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works perfectly well but is a bit of a joke as well because the first thing I thought when I read your question was 'Who still literally uses man from the command line? Doesn't everyone just Google the man page they want (so that they get fancy things like unlimited scrolling)?'. Then I realized that the sites I Google usually all have both types of commands so why not just use them to provide a uniform man page interface across all commands. Hence, this fun was born.

This requires an Internet connnection for any entries you haven't already looked up at least once. It also needs these two small apps which are missing in a default installation of Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install tidy html2text
```

These aren't absolutely needed but they do help make it look a little nicer. Tidy will clean the HTML and html2text will format that html as formatted text (which is usually pretty trivial since most of these sites are already text formatted and just wrapped in <pre> tags.

Now all you need to do is add this to the end of `~/.profile`:

```
function iman() {
    if [ ! -d "/usr/share/iman" ]; then
        sudo mkdir -m a=rwx /usr/share/iman
    fi
    if [ ! -f "/usr/share/iman/$1.html" ]; then
        curl "http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?$1"| tidy -n -asxml 2>/dev/null| html2text > "/usr/share/iman/$1.html"; 
    fi
    if [ -f "/usr/share/iman/$1.html" ]; then
        cat "/usr/share/iman/$1.html";
    else
        echo "Entry not found."
    fi
}
```

After you logout and then back in you should be able to type this:

```
iman cd
```

and it'll display the man page for `cd`.

This uses a data directory (/usr/share/iman) in order to minimize our network requirements (so it'll work for entries you've already found before even without the connection; also to minimize load on this random linux man pages site I found with the system entries we want in it as well). If you don't use this anymore you'll want to remove that to recover disk space.

Hopefully, the rest is pretty straight forward.

Comment: 'Who still literally uses man from the command line?` Me! and everyone else that has to visit a datacenter (no internet ;) )

Comment: Point taken, this won't help you then to be clear.

Comment: I would think the opposit, I rarely ever use Google to look up bash commands. It's a lot faster to just type "man command" without having to leave the keyboard.

Comment: alt+tab -> alt+d -> command will do the same without mouse and without canceling the current cli command and with scrolling and with a million other nice things a browser gives you. I'm sure you wouldn't know anything about that because your alway use this site and others like it from lynx...ffs

Comment: In case of builtins, your `iman` function return the same output as `man bash-builtins`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Well, unless I find a site which uses something like what you've posted to retrieve the documentation then this will be no better than your solution in any way really.