# No man-page or info-page for type command

Tags: command-line, bash, documentation, manpage

I tried to find information about [`type`](http://ss64.com/bash/type.html) command using man pages and info

```
$ man type 
No manual entry for type
info type
```

I think this is info menu page.
[image: info return]

Is it just happening to me?? Why did Ubuntu developers remove `type` command manual page. Did they ever make a manual page for `type` command?

Comment: You are mistaken. http://askubuntu.com/questions/445749/whats-the-difference-between-shell-builtin-and-shell-keyword  It is a bash built-in so the man page is inside `man bash` and is shown with `help type`.

Comment: @Rinzwind I get this from `man bash | grep type` http://imgur.com/a/xxn3x is this the manual entry you are referring to .

Comment: Also, @Rinzwind seems to be assuming this user is using bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you enter `type type` you find that

```
type is a shell builtin
```

So its documentation is in `man bash`. You can't get the instructions from `man type` but you can instead get them from (many thanks to @Rinzwind ) `help type` and in the same format as a man page with the `-m` option and by piping the output into `less`

```
help -m type | less
```

`man bash` is very long, and may be easier to read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), specifically the section on [bash builtin commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins).

Here is the entry for `type`, which tells us what kind of command a command is:

> **type**
>
> ```
> type [-afptP] [name …]
> ```
>
> For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a command name.
>   If the -t option is used, type prints a single word which is one of >‘alias’, ‘function’, ‘builtin’, ‘file’ or ‘keyword’, if name is an
>   alias, shell function, shell builtin, disk file, or shell reserved
>   word, respectively. If the name is not found, then nothing is printed,
>   and type returns a failure status.
>
> If the -p option is used, type either returns the name of the disk file that would be executed, or nothing if -t would not return ‘file’.
>
> The -P option forces a path search for each name, even if -t would not return ‘file’.
>
> If a command is hashed, -p and -P print the hashed value, which is not necessarily the file that appears first in $PATH.
>
> If the -a option is used, type returns all of the places that contain an executable named file. This includes aliases and functions,
>   if and only if the -p option is not also used.
>
> If the -f option is used, type does not attempt to find shell functions, as with the command builtin.
>
> The return status is zero if all of the names are found, non-zero if any are not found.

**Examples**:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type sort
sort is /usr/bin/sort
$ type python
python is hashed (/usr/bin/python)
```

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/439411/527764) gives a really clever way to make the `man` command work for shell builtin commands by adding a function to your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: If Rinzwind is correct then I am afraid your answer is wrong, because technically there is a manual entry for type but its sort of invisible due to its wrong placement.

Comment: @Creator Rinzwind is totally right of course! I edited...

Comment: What is the reason that builtin shell commands aren't in manual pages.

Comment: @Creator well they are in the man page for bash itself, as Rinzwind said, and the `help` page has the info from that page, and can be styled like a `man` page with the `-m` option (I am editing...) so it would be a duplication really. See link at the end now for how to make `man` work for builtin commands with a clever trick