# How to find a command not in man or info

Tags: command-line, manpage, info

I am trying to find alert but can't find it under man or info. I found a similar question involving type and it turned out it was under bash. How does one find a command like this without having to go through google? Also if anyone knows how to get alert that would certainly help as well.

type link:
[No man-page or info-page for type command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801289/no-man-page-or-info-page-for-type-command)

Comment: The linked post already shows how to use `type` to determine what various commands actually are (see for example, `ls` being an alias to `ls` itself. You should have read that answer more thoroughly.

Comment: You are correct however I didn't know that was what I was looking for. It was for a homework assignment and it sounded like my teacher wanted something like a man page. I asked him today and he confirmed type was actually what he was looking for. However I also wanted to know multiple ways to do this for future sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, I turn to the help screen of the application that I am trying to find.

```
~$ alert --help
Usage:
  notify-send [OPTION...] <SUMMARY> [BODY] - create a notification

Help Options:
  -?, --help                        Show help options

Application Options:
  -u, --urgency=LEVEL               Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).
  -t, --expire-time=TIME            Specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to expire the notification.
  -a, --app-name=APP_NAME           Specifies the app name for the icon
  -i, --icon=ICON[,ICON...]         Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.
  -c, --category=TYPE[,TYPE...]     Specifies the notification category.
  -h, --hint=TYPE:NAME:VALUE        Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid types are int, double, string and byte.
  -v, --version                     Version of the package.
```

As the help screen shows, alert is actually `notify-send`, and if you run `type alert` you will see that it is aliased to `notify-send` as it is actually not a package installed separately.

```
~$ type alert
alert is aliased to `notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//')"'
```

And if you type in `alias` by itself, it will show you all the aliases that are setup for you.

```
~$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Comment: This answer is really great. I needed to see what alert actually did and after looking at both the man page for notify-send and the type for alert I see that alert is nothing more than an implementation of notify-send. Thank you very much.